# What is causing this spacing between my PyQt layouts?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

```
import sys

from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *


class collapsibleSection(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, title="", *content: QWidget, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.arrowButton = QPushButton()
        self.titleLabel = QLabel(title)

        self.titleFrame = QFrame(self)

        self.setFrameStyle(QFrame.Shape.Box)
        self.setLineWidth(1)
        self.contentFrameH = QFrame(self)
        self.contentFrameHLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.contentFrameV = QFrame(self)
        self.contentFrameVLayout = QVBoxLayout()


        self.init_ui(*content)

    def init_ui(self, *content: QWidget):
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)

        self.arrowButton.setCheckable(True)
        self.arrowButton.setFlat(True)
        self.arrowButton.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton {
                border: none;
                background-color: transparent;
            }

            QPushButton:checked {
                background-color: transparent;
            }

            QPushButton:hover {
                background-color: none;
            }
        """)
        self.arrowButton.toggled.connect(self._toggle_collapse)
        self.arrowButton.setFixedWidth(16)
        self.arrowButton.setFixedHeight(16)

        self.titleLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignVCenter)
        self.titleLabel.setStyleSheet("font-weight: bold;")

        titleFrameLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        titleFrameLayout.addWidget(self.arrowButton)
        titleFrameLayout.addWidget(self.titleLabel)

        self.titleFrame.setLayout(titleFrameLayout)

        self.contentFrameH.setLayout(self.contentFrameHLayout)
        self.contentFrameV.setLayout(self.contentFrameVLayout)

        # set up visual indent for content in widget

        self.contentFrameHLayout.addSpacing(20)

        self.setContent(*content)

        layout.addWidget(self.titleFrame)
        layout.addWidget(self.contentFrameH)

        # self.contentFrameH.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Policy.Expanding)
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Shape.NoFrame)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self._toggle_collapse()

    def _toggle_collapse(self):
        if not self.arrowButton.isChecked():
            self.arrowButton.setText("▶")
            self.contentFrameH.hide()
        else:
            self.arrowButton.setText("▼")
            self.contentFrameH.show()

    def setTitle(self, title: str):
        self.titleLabel.setText(title)

    def setContent(self, *content: QWidget):
        # the -1 is to avoid removing the spacerItem
        for i in reversed(range(self.contentFrameHLayout.count() - 1)):
            self.contentFrameHLayout.itemAt(i).widget().setParent(None)

        for w in content:
            w.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Policy.Fixed)
            self.contentFrameVLayout.addWidget(w)
            self.contentFrameHLayout.addWidget(self.contentFrameV)



class infoWindowBase(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.centralWidget.setEnabled(True)
        self.centralWidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")

        self.primaryGridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.primaryGridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.primaryGridLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.primaryGridLayout.setObjectName("primaryGridLayout")

        self.scrollArea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setSpacing(10)
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)
        self.scrollWidget = QWidget(self)
        self.scrollWidget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollWidget)


        comfyLayout = QVBoxLayout()  # used to add content margins around scrollArea for better aesthetics
        comfyLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 10, 0, 10)
        comfyLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        comfyFrame = QFrame()
        comfyFrame.setLayout(comfyLayout)

        self.primaryGridLayout.addWidget(comfyFrame, 1, 0)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)


class employeeInfo(infoWindowBase):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._medicalData = QLabel("DATA HERE")
        self._medicalSection = collapsibleSection()
        self._initEmployeeData()

    def _initEmployeeData(self):
        # medical data setup
        medicalFrame = QFrame(self._medicalSection)
        medicalLayout = QVBoxLayout(medicalFrame)

        medicalLayout.addWidget(self._medicalData)

        medicalFrame.setLayout(medicalLayout)

        self._medicalSection.setTitle("Medical Data")
        self._medicalSection.setContent(medicalFrame)

        self.layout.addWidget(self._medicalSection)
        self.layout.addSpacing(20)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
w = employeeInfo()
w.show()
app.exec()
```

Here is the spacing in question:

[image]

I would like to know how I can change said spacing.

I already tried adjust all of the layouts content margins/spacing for the collapsible section class but none of it actually changed the spacing. I want to minimize the space between the title and the contentFrameH.

[image: Here is a picture of the issue.]

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Sorry, but this is not a debugging service, and since we have no way of easily run your code, I sincerely doubt anybody would read through almost 400 lines of code. Also, ensure that everything is within a single code block.

Comment: sorry about that. this is my first post

Comment: Sorry, but your code is still *not* reproducible, as it uses imports we know nothing about. Please consider that you should only include aspects of the program that are actually necessary to reproduce the problem, while anything not related to it should be removed or simplified. For instance, I sincerely doubt that the `windowWithTitleBar` implementation will have anything to do with the problem, so, just use a basic QWidget instead.

Comment: Now it works! Really sorry about taht.

Comment: No, it doesn't. We still don't have the contents of `stylesheets` nor `icons`. A MRE must be something we can easily copy, paste and run, possibly without any substantial modification. In any case, just use `setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` for the other layouts. Also, remove the `self` argument in `self.contentFrameVLayout = QVBoxLayout(self)`.

Comment: guarantee you it is MRE now. thank you for your help so far though.

Comment: Did you try to `setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)` for *all* inner layouts as suggested before?

Comment: I have just realized that it is a combination of the titleFrameLayout and both contentFrame layouts. I have the result I need now. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: [QTreeWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/tutorials/basictutorial/treewidget.html) might be interesting for you. Also you can answer your own question here, if somebody else finds it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a combination of the titleFrameLayout and both contentFrame layouts. I solved it by adjusting the content Margins for all 3 layouts.